# Magento 2: Change price + tier prices of configurable product and variants afterwards

Tags: magento2, price, tierprice

We run Magento 2.1.7 and want to change prices and tier prices of configurable products' variants. Doing that seems to be really painstaking as
- price input field of configurable product is disabled after first save and
- it seems that you have to edit every product variant's price separately.

Even if changing tier prices on every simple product variant tier prices from master article are used. The cannot be edited after product was saved once.

Honestly, that should be a basic feature of a shop system these days. Has anyone the same problem and/or a solution how I can change price of configurable product afterwards?